# How can I use the responseType is 'stream' in axios post method in React-native?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, axios, streaming

When I try to call the axios post method with responceType of 'stream' it gives the warning that 'LogBox.js:154 The provided value 'stream' is not a valid 'responseType'. but the same code will work in node.js with axios version ^1.5.0.

I have the code that you all can refer that
This is the Node.js code. And in that you can see that in the response.data have the 'on' enent which is use to stream the text.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const { log } = require('console');

const url = "url-of-chat-stream";

const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const requestData = {
      "user_id": "11",
      "question": "what are some inspirational books to read and some ideas to improve reading habits?"
    };

    const response = await axios.post(url, requestData, {
      responseType: 'stream',
      headers: {
        accept: 'application/json',
      },
    });

    log(response.data, '<====')

    response.data.on('data', (chunk) => {
      if (chunk) {
        console.log(chunk.toString('utf-8'));
      }
    });

    response.data.on('end', () => {
      console.log('Streaming complete');
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error.message);
  }
};
fetchData();
```

but this same code will not work in the React or React-Native because of the adapter is used in the library. It will only give the JSON formated data

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2159.